# Pros and cons closing a browser while session variable is set in rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

just wanted to know:

In my rails 3 app when a user logs in, i store their id in a session variable like this

```
session[:id] = @user.id
```

i noticed that when i login and then close the browser the session is destroyed. Is this wise to do or better to create a logout feature to destroy the sessions. What can go wrong if i leave it as is.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I noticed that when I login and then
>   close the browser the session is
>   destroyed. Is this wise to do.

If this is happening then it's good if session get expired/destroyed when user closes browser. This is what mostly done in websites.But can be hard when you are trying to providing *remember me* or *always sign in* like functionality. In this case you might not have to destroy session when browser is closed.

> or create a logout feature to destroy
>   the sessions.

You can create a logout feature to destroy session but call this when user hits logout link.